# Stored procedure calling error on python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, stored-procedures, mysql-python

Python script

```
cursor = self.cursor
data = cursor.execute("call tests('test_site_name',@result);SELECT @result")
print(data) // return 1
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row) // None
```

I use import MySQLdb library. Does MySQLdb not support stored procedures? It works on myphpadmin but it is not work on python 3. Please on my code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tests`(IN `sitename` VARCHAR(100), OUT `_group_id` VARCHAR(100))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
 SELECT sitename INTO _group_id ;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You say there is an error but you have not provided us with the error so that we can try and help out.

Comment: this  should be output test_site_name but i got only 1 and None. On myphpadmin , it return test_site_name. So that i didn't know what is wrong.